# Invite to Facebook Game App with invite token from invitable_friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can fetch my invitable_friends list, and retrieve an invite token for each one:

```
 ["data": [
{
  "id": "inviteTokenA",
  "name": "User A"
},
{
  "id": "inviteTokenB",
  "name": "User B"
}..]
```

Then, I want to invite "User A" to my Game App. I'm trying to do it with a POST request like: "/me/apprequests", with params (message = "Some message", to = "inviteTokenA")

*(If a don't send the "message" parameter, I get an error response)*

I guess it's not the proper way, because I've got a success response:

```
  {
    "request": "6029343172911",
    "to": [
      "someID"
    ]
  }
```

And **someID** is my Facebook ID, no matter what I send as "to" parameter.
I mean, it's an app request to myself.

And if I try to make request "/**inviteTokenA**/apprequests"  I get:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: AVnop7tyDDSaYC0FQYRQNIKOTIHQcmYJk2c-uSF1fLf1UUNbc0WXKt62lhLvvJZdSUrxHyYTdxFUCTkLDw6ON_I1qinF3rq6HVVfU0m7jzgj7w",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "DrHiMQl8jWT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send *invites* via API.

The user of your app needs to send them via the Request Dialog, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#launchingrequestdialog

When calling that dialog, you can pass one or more of the tokens you get from the invitable_friends endpoint.